# Zookeeper behind AWS ELB with Mesos

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mesos, amazon-elb

Has anyone managed to get Mesos to talk to Zookeeper through AWS ELB.

My initial experiment has been no.

I have zookeeper on an ASG with Netflix Exhibitor. The thing that bugs me is when zk instances are replaced, I have to reconfigure all servers in the Mesos cluster. Not difficult, but the rolling restart along is annoying enough.

Answer (score 0):

I set up route53 internal VPC DNS which uses an ELB.  Setting CNAME of zk.internal.com:2181 as the ZK instance seem to work so far.  We aren't running in production yet though, so I don't know what kind of problems will arise then.